# ClickOnce Visual Studio Express

Tags: clickonce

I am using visual studio express edition, I tried to use ClickOnce to make a setup.exe file but when I take it to another laptop I get the error 26 message.
Is it possible to make a setup with VS express edition?

Comment: This is the error message I go: "A network related instance error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: SQL Server Network Interface, error – 26- Error locating server/instance specified"

Comment: check your SQL connection string. *Server* attribute to be more specific

Comment: I'm not sure what that means (I am a beginner) but since it works on machine A what shouldn't work on machine B?

Comment: does not always work, *A* may have a different configuration to *B*, check that *B* have access to the connection string set to *A*

Comment: Ok I think you made me understand something, I have not done anything to machine B, I simply insert the USB drive and try to run the setup.

Comment: If it's not to much trouble for you, how do you give access to machine B?